# Django pointfield admin widget shows wrong point (long/lat switch places)

Tags: django, gdal, geos, django-geoposition

I have a model with PointField.

```
class Companion(models.Model):
   startpoint = models.PointField(srid=4326, null=True)
```

My admin.py file

```
class CompanionAdmin(admin.GISModelAdmin):
   pass
admin.site.register(Companion, CompanionAdmin)
```

When I set point in django admin and save it, all looks good.
But when i try to find saved coordinates on map, it didn't find anything. As I found out it happens because coordinates switch their places (long is lat, lat is long).

I used different admin classes, such as LeafletGeoAdmin, GISModelAdmin, it didn't help.

How can I fix it?